# На каком языке написан данный код? И что он обозначает?

Tags: идентификация

```
$var[0] = HGET(100,100)
WNDSTATE($var [0], 1)
LDOWN(500,300)
```

Comment: Похапэ. Может означать что угодно.

Comment: @Эникейщик почему сразу похапэ? это собственный синтаксис кликермана

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да в таком виде это может быть почти что угодно, что разрешает знак доллара в именах переменных

Comment: @andreymal именно так)

Comment: @Эникейщик а вот кстати похапэ не подходит, потому что нет обязательных точек с запятой)

Comment: @andreymal ну да, не пишу давно на таких языках, позабыл 

Answer (score 3):

Это код программы [кликерман](https://clickermann.ru/) (инструмент, позволяющий автоматически, на программном уровне, выполнять в среде Windows различные команды и действия, которые обычно выполняет пользователь в ручном режиме)

`HGET` - возвращает дескриптор (HWND) для элемента по заданным координатам

`WNDSTATE` - сворачивает (разворачивает) окно

```
WNDSTATE (hwnd, state) 

hwnd - HWND окна
state - состояние {0 - свернуто, 1 - развернуто}
```

`LDOWN` - Зажать левую клавишу

```
LDOWN (x, y) - зажимает левую клавишу мышки

x, y - координаты, в которые будет помещен курсор перед тем как произвести действие
```

---

Команды есть тут:

https://clickermann1.ru/komandy/

и тут

https://clickermann-help.netlify.app/

и где угодно ещё

Comment: Что мне нужно изменить в коде что бы он зажимал ЛКМ в одном положении в свёрнутом режиме?

Comment: @iAppIe, чтобы задать новый вопрос, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)", которая находится справа вверху страницы.